# In Haskell, where does the range ['a'..] stop?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell for fun, following [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com). Range can go to infinity with numbers when using `[1..]`. With characters, where does the range `['a'..]` stop ? I kinda suppose the last character of the Unicode table, but I really know nothing about Haskell so just asking !

Comment: so you think that asking here a question is better than trying it in `ghci`?

Comment: It's easier to see with `[False ..]`, which evaluates to simply `[False, True]`.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ I tried, and I just saw a never-ending sequence of \45651 that looked like Unicode characaters code. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm curious to understand how `[False..]` relates to `['a'..]`.

Comment: the [foo..] notation is valid if foo is an Enum. Both Bool and Char declare an Enum instance.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, didn't know about that (I know nothing about Haskell anyway...).

Comment: It stops at `last ['a'..]`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [Haskell Report 2010](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html):

> The character type Char is an enumeration whose values represent
>   Unicode characters. Type Char is an instance of the classes Read, Show, Eq,
>   Ord, Enum, and Bounded.

So in theory, this range should stop at the last character defined in the [Unicode standard](http://unicode.org/standard/standard.html) (though it's not stated which version). In practice, your Haskell implementation may vary, e.g. GHCI 7.6.2 stops at \1114111.

Comment: A bit technical for me since I haven't studied yet Haskell's type system, but a very good answer. Thanks !

Comment: Erm, \1114111 *is* the last "character thingy". (scare quotes because 'character' is often an ambiguous term; more correct would be something like 'Unicode scalar value')

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, agree. In fact they're called ["Unicode code point"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)

Comment: FWIW, the only version with a lower limit (0xFFFF) is Unicode 1.0, which stopped being current more than 17 years ago. All others have the same limit: 0x10FFFF.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Though the last two codepoints in each plane are permanently unassigned, so I guess the greatest possible assignable codepoint would be U+10FFFD. (Not sure if that makes a difference . . .)

Comment: @ruakh No, they are not permanently *unassigned*. They are permanently *reserved* for internal use. They are called noncharacters, but they are not illegal in Unicode data. Their exchange is somewhat discouraged (after all, they are for internal use), but not even that is explicitly forbidden (more info http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#noncharacters)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thanks for that link. It says that "They are considered unassigned to any abstract character, and they share the General_Category value Cn (Unassigned) with unassigned reserved code points in the standard", so I don't think it's unreasonable to call them "unassigned". The FAQ seems to recommend that they be treated, when possible, like other unrecognized characters.

Answer (score 56):

If you want to know where the range stops, just get the last item…

```
ghci> last ['a'.. ]
'\1114111'
```

Another method: `Char` is a bounded type, i.e. a type with minimum and maximum values defined. Types in the `Bounded` class provide a `maxBound` value. Since `maxBound` is polymorphic, you have to explicitly state the type of the value you're looking for.

```
ghci> maxBound :: Char
'\1114111'
ghci> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
```

There is no `maxBound` for `Integer` since they are unbounded.

The [Haskell prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aEnum) explains the connection between `['a'..]` and `maxBound`. The notation `['a'..]` is syntactic sugar for `enumFrom a`; here `enumFrom` is a method of the `Enum` type class. The documentation of `Enum` specifies that when the type is also an instance of `Bounded`, `enumFrom x` should be equivalent to `enumFromTo x maxBound`, or more readably, `[x..] = [x..maxBound]`. So the last element of `['a'..]` must be the same as `maxBound :: Char`.

`last ['a'.. ]` does iterate over the list, but a modern computer can count to a million in an eyeblink. It's not something you would want to put in a tight loop, but as something you run just once it isn't a big burden. If you try it out in a less optimized implementation such as Hugs instead of GHC, you may need to wait for the result. In contrast `last [0..]` would take approximately forever.

Comment: `last ['a'..]` is clever, I haven't thought about that. I've tested it in ghci and was expecting it to be long, since `length ['a'..]` is 1114015. But it was instantaneous. My understanding is that Haskell is lazy, so it has to evaluate the whole list to find the last. Is it true for `last ['a'..]` ? If it is, how can it be so fast ?

Comment: Also, I don't understand `maxBound :: Char`. Willing to give a short explanation ? I suppose I'll understand it as I continue to learn, but I'm curious.

Comment: `maxBound` (the opposite is `minBound`) means maximum value for types that are in the `Bounded` class - types that have maximum and minium values defined. Since it's polymorphic you have to explicitly state the type of the value you're looking for (for example the maximum value for `Int` is `maxBound :: Int`)

Comment: @DjebbZ even if it did evaluate the entire list, counting to a billion is no taxing task for the modern cpu.

Comment: @DjebbZ: the [Haskell prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Enum) explains the connection between `['a'..]` and `maxBound`.  The notation `['a'..]` is syntactic sugar for `enumFrom a`; here `enumFrom` is a method of the `Enum` type class.  The documentation of `Enum` specifies that when the type is also an instance of `Bounded`, `enumFrom x` should be equivalent to `enumFromTo x maxBound`, or more readably, `[x..] = [x..maxBound]`. So the last element of `['a'..]` *must* be the same as `maxBound :: Char`.

Comment: @JustinL. indeed. The learnyouahaskell tutorial made it sound like going through a big array was slow since it had to be evaluated. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: @DjebbZ There's slow as in "don't put it in a loop", and there's slow as in "causes a delay that annoys a human." Loads of things that are "slow" in the former sense are fast enough to do a small fixed number of times (like one) without causing a noticeable delay. So both JustinL and learnyouahaskell are right, for different definitions of "slow".